# Is a refund for the return leg of a cheap China Airlines ticket possible?

Tags: refunds, china-airlines

I ordered a cheap return ticket from China Airlines and I'm not going to be able to make the return leg back home.

Is there any possible way to refund the ticket?

Or at least get some of my cash back?

Usually cheap tickets don't allow this right?

Should I just give up and consider it insurance for my trip (i.e. I needed it in case I had to leave the country at this time)?

Edit: Refunds not allowed.

But perhaps a change is possible i.e. change date of the return leg flight for the change in fare price?

Maybe change to leave in 6 months or 1 year?

China Airlines ICN->TPE->BNE  $400 AUD

> Seoul - Brisbane Change conditions
>
> ```
> Before Departure
>     Changes*: Allowed with restrictions
>     Reissue: Allowed with restrictions
>     Penalty fee for ticket reissue between: 55.00 AUD / 55.00 AUD
>     Penalty fee for changes* between: 55.00 AUD / 55.00 AUD (at today exchange rates 55.00 AUD / 55.00 AUD)
>     Maximum Revalidation penalty fee for entire ticket 55.00 AUD
> No-show for first CI/AE flight
>     Changes*: Not applicable (See reissue conditions)
>     Reissue: Not allowed
> After Departure
>     Changes*: Allowed with restrictions
>     Penalty fee for changes between: 55.00 AUD / 55.00 AUD (at today exchange rates 55.00 AUD / 55.00 AUD)
>     Reissue: Allowed with restrictions
>     Penalty fee for ticket reissue between: 55.00 AUD / 55.00 AUD)
> No-show for subsequent flight(s)
>     Changes*: Not applicable (See reissue conditions)
>     Reissue: Not allowed
> ```

I know I will have to return back to Brisbane in at least a year's time.

Should I try to change my flight and extend the travel date until I will return?

Also will their staff in Seoul speak English?

Would I be able to walk into the office and request a change?

Is that silly to try?

Comment: You have almost too many questions to answer in one go.

Comment: You'll be charged $55 AUD plus the difference in fare for changing the ticket. But you need to call the airline before the flight segment (that you will not fly) departs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is shown in airfare rules you pasted, changes are possible for a fee of AU$55, but there also may be a change in airfare if the fare class you originally bought your ticket in is full or not available on the new date you choose.  This airfare difference can go either way.

The original fare rules may also have a period of validity, so depending on how long ago you took the outbound flight, you maybe limited on how far in the future you can plan the return flight. This can sometimes be gotten around by paying for a higher fare.

Best bet is to get in touch with the airline sooner rather than later to explore the available options and fare differences.

Likely you will find English speaking staff at their call center and at their main Seoul ticket office. China Airlines flies a lot of traffic from Australia, USA, Canada, etc to Asian destinations, so would have at least a few English speaking staff at each major Asian destination they market to these countries.  And there is no real advantage to or difference between visiting their ticket office versus calling on the phone.